# Errors with elsarticle document class

Tags: symbols, packages, incompatibility

I'm using the `elsarticle` document class on ShareLaTeX, and it is giving five errors that don't make much sense to me.

My code is

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{pifont, natbib, geometry, fleqn, graphicx, txfonts,hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,parskip}

\title{plasma paper}
\author{Garrett Young}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Lorentz force equations:
\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{F} = \mathbf{-\mathit{e}(E + v \times B)} = m\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

And the errors are

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty, line 505
LaTeX Error: Command \iint already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.505 ...d{\iint}{\DOTSI\protect\MultiIntegral{2}}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
 /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty, line 506
LaTeX Error: Command \iiint already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.506 ...{\iiint}{\DOTSI\protect\MultiIntegral{3}}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
 /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty, line 507
LaTeX Error: Command \iiiint already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.507 ...\iiiint}{\DOTSI\protect\MultiIntegral{4}}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
 /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty, line 508
LaTeX Error: Command \idotsint already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.508 ...dotsint}{\DOTSI\protect\MultiIntegral{0}}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
 /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fleqn.sty
inputting `fleqn.clo' instead of obsolete `fleqn.sty'.
```

The content shows up correctly. I don't really know what's wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of symbols defined inside [`txfonts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/txfonts) that are also defined in [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), so you can just make these available again:

```
\usepackage{txfonts}
\let\iint\relax
\let\iiint\relax
\let\iiiint\relax
\let\idotsint\relax
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

However, the following is better:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum \ldots

\end{document}
```

From the [`newtx` README](http://ctan.org/pkg/newtx):

> The bun­dle splits `tx­fonts.sty` (from the [TX fonts](http://ctan.org/pkg/txfonts) dis­tri­bu­tion) into two in­de­pen­dent pack­ages, `newtx­text.sty` and `newtx­math.sty`, each with fixes and enhancements.

It seems like the fixes might include the symbol definitions being removed.

Comment: Thank you, this works beautifully - +1. Do you have any idea about the  warning (" /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fleqn.sty
inputting fleqn.clo instead of obsolete fleqn.sty")?

Comment: @heather: Yes. Use flesh as a document class or package option, not by loading the package explicitly.